# Copy table data from one object to another object AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I'm trying to do a Job which used to Copy and insert Journal Names from one entity to another entity. Below code able to handle only fields only I hardcoded. But I'm trying to do a code which will be useful in future i.e if we add new custom field to the table. My code should able to copy data of that newly custom field added.

```
static void sa_CopyData(Args _args)
{
    LedgerJournalName   tblLedgerJournalNameSource, tblLedgerJournalNameDesination;
    NumberSequenceTable tblNST, tblNSTCopy;
    NumberSequenceScope tblNSS;
    Counter             countIN, countOUT;
    DataAreaId          sourceEntity, destinationEntity;

    sourceEntity    = 'CNUS';
    destinationEntity = 'CNEN';
    //Journal Names creation
    changeCompany(sourceEntity)
    {
        tblLedgerJournalNameSource = null;
        while select * from tblLedgerJournalNameSource
            where tblLedgerJournalNameSource.dataAreaId == sourceEntity
        {
            ++countIN;
            tblNSTcopy = null; tblNST = null; tblNSS = null;

            select * from tblNSTcopy
            where tblNSTCopy.RecId == tblLedgerJournalNameSource.NumberSequenceTable;

            changeCompany(destinationEntity)
            {
                tblNST = null; tblNSS = null; tblLedgerJournalNameDesination = null;

                select * from tblNST
                    join tblNSS
                    where tblNST.NumberSequenceScope == tblNSS.RecId
                    && tblNST.NumberSequence == tblNSTCopy.NumberSequence
                    && tblNSS.DataArea == destinationEntity;

                //Insert only if Journal name is not exists
                if(!(LedgerJournalName::find(tblLedgerJournalNameSource.JournalName)))
                {
                    ttsBegin;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.initValue();
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.JournalName = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.JournalName;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.Name = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.Name;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.JournalType = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.JournalType;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.ApproveActive = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.ApproveActive;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.ApproveGroupId = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.ApproveGroupId;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.NoAutoPost = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.NoAutoPost;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.WorkflowApproval = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.WorkflowApproval;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.Configuration = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.Configuration;
                    if (!tblNST.RecId)
                    {
                        info(strFmt('Number Sequence is not updated for %1 > Entity %2', tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.JournalName, destinationEntity));
                    }
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.NumberSequenceTable = tblNST.recid;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.NewVoucher = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.NewVoucher;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.BlockUserGroupId = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.BlockUserGroupId;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.FixedOffsetAccount = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.FixedOffsetAccount;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.OffsetAccountType = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.OffsetAccountType;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.OffsetLedgerDimension = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.OffsetLedgerDimension;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.LedgerJournalInclTax = tblLedgerJournalNameSource.LedgerJournalInclTax;
                    tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.insert();
                    ttsCommit;
                    ++countOUT;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    info(strFmt('Journal Names Creation > Read: %1, Inserted: %2', countIN, countOUT));
}
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `buf2buf(from, to)`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/global.buf2buf.aspx

It does **not** perform an insert, so after you do `buf2buf()` you can modify any fields you want in the target before doing an insert.

You could do `tblLedgerJournalNameDesination.data(tblLedgerJournalNameSource);` but that also copies system fields, which you most likely do not want.

You can also look at the source code behind `Global::buf2Buf(from, to)` and modify that logic if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex. But I can't the change entity from "CNUS" to "CNEN".

Comment: Also, in some cases you can use `y.data(x)` to copy all fields from x to y. I do not recall if this can be used in a cross company scenario like here.

Comment: @SankarR - Yes you can. You still do `changeCompany()`. See http://fourone.se/blog/2007/11/07/intercompany-with-buf2buf/#more-20